# org.hibernate.UnsupportedLockAttemptException: Lock mode not supported : Hibernate 4->5 Upgrade

Tags: spring, hibernate

We've just upgraded Hibernate 4->5 in our application. The following code used to work in Hibernate 4. There is a job which fetches some data from `MAIL_HISTORY_T` and can optionally write into `MAIL_HISTORY_T` as well in the same transaction.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Scheduled(cron = "${mail.cron.reviewer.task.reminder}") 
public void sendPendingReviewerTaskRemainderEmail() {
    //...
    for(Reviewers reviewer: pendingTasks) {
        // Read from MAIL_HISTORY_T
        MailHistory mh = mailHistoryDAO.getMailHistoryByReqId(reviewer.getReqId()); 
        //...
        if (someCondition) {
            // Write to MAIL_HISTORY_T
            mailHistoryDAO.createNewMailHistory(reviewer.getReqId(), params); 
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.UnsupportedLockAttemptException: Lock mode not supported
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ImmutableEntityEntry.setLockMode(ImmutableEntityEntry.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireRefresh(SessionImpl.java:1295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.refresh(SessionImpl.java:1247) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at app.mcs.dao.MailHistoryDAO.persist(MailHistoryDAO.java:40) ~[classes/:]
```

Both the Read and Write operations on `MAIL_HISTORY_T` reference the same Request ID.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this by rewriting the **Write operation as Native SQL**. The Read operation remains unchanged as before.

Therefore, the previous Hibernate-based `createNewMailHistory()` is now Native SQL:

```
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery("insert "
            + "    into "
            + "        MAIL_HISTORY_T "
            + "        (ID, MAIL_TEMPLATE_ID, MAIL_IDENTIFIER, REQUEST_ID, SYSTEM_COMMENTS, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY) "
            + "    values "
            + "        (nextval('mh_seq'), :mailTemplateId, :mailIdentifier, :requestId, :systemComments, :createdDate, :createdBy)")
        .setParameter("mailTemplateId", mailTemplateDAO.findByShortIdentifier(mailIdentifier).getId())
        .setParameter("mailIdentifier", mailIdentifier)
        .setParameter("requestId", req.getId())
        .setParameter("systemComments", systemComments)
        .setParameter("createdDate", new Date())
        .setParameter("createdBy", null)
        .executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your code is creating [ImmutableEntityEntry](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/internal/ImmutableEntityEntry.html) which is new introduction in Hibernate 5.

As per `ImmutableEntityEntry` code, it only support `LockMode.NONE` & `LockMode.READ` (see `ImmutableEntityEntry#setLockMode` method).

Your code is reading & updating same entity so it is most likely hibernate is setting LockMode as `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` which is not supported by `ImmutableEntityEntry`.

<strike>Can you please check which `AbstractEntityEntry` instance you were receiving prior to Hibernate 5 update.</strike>

Edit :- There already exists a bug in hibernate regarding this https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13601.

Currently,I am not sure how you can obtain `MutableEntityEntry` in your case which will help you to change your entity.

Comment: What's the easiest way to check it? Can I output `AbstractEntityEntry` in my own code? That takes place behind Hibernate's wall.

Comment: @geneb.  well, I have found out bug already raised in Hibernate, updating my answer.

Comment: thanks that's great to know. The bug was created in 2019, though, still no resolution

Comment: yeah, that's true, though I am certainly not sure how you can obtain `MutableEntityEntry` in your scenario. Because that might be helpful for you so that you can change your entity after reading.

Comment: We fixed this by rewriting the Write as Native SQL, answer below.

Comment: Good to know, I upvoted it as it might be beneficial for community